# shortcut for Eventvwr > Connect to another computer

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, batch, eventviewer

I was wondering if you can write the following action in a batch command?

1. `eventvwr` (open the event viewer)
2. Menu Action > Connect to another computer
3. Type in the name of the computer.
4. Connect.

This would make my life just a few minutes/day more efficient ;-)

**Update**
As we've just upgraded to Windows 7 and I needed a new solution, it seems to be possible like this:

`%windir%\system32\eventvwr.exe targethostname`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I haven't been googling enough before asking this question.

The solution is this :

```
eventvwr.msc /computer=hostname
```

don't forget the .msc or it won't accept the parameter

You can immediately put this in a shortcut if you want, it seems to work great!

**[Edit]**
This only works for Windows XP!

Comment: I didn't know about this one... but I just tried it, and it doesn't seem to work (at least on Windows 7). I've tried "eventvwr.msc hostname", "eventvwr.msc /computer=hostname", "mmc.exe eventvwr.msc hostname" and "mmc.exe eventvwr.msc /computer=hostname": none of them worked, they always connected to the local event logs.

Comment: Works on XP and Server 2003 but sadly must agree that it doesn't work on Win7, although the target machine may be Win7.

Comment: I should have mentioned this earlier but my case was specifically for Windows XP. I can't find anything for Windows 7 either.

Answer (score 6):

For Windows 7 the command is `eventvwr hostname`

Answer (score 3):

That `eventvwr` actually means `eventwvr.msc`, which is not an executable file: it's a saved MMC console, and it gets opened by the main MMC executable, `mmc.exe`.

Unfortunately, this means you just can't pass it any command-line parameter, beside those that are understood by `mmc.exe` (which are very few, and totally unrelated to connecting to another computer).

An option you can explore is creating your own custom MMC, by launching an empty console (just run `mmc.exe`) and adding snap-ins to it, including some instances of the Event Viewer one connected to other computers; then you can save this console, and when you'll open it later it will already be configured to show you those remote event logs.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows Versions greater than XP you can still use eventviewer.msc.

But the event viewer snap-in only accepts the colon and not the equal sign.

```
mmc eventvwr.msc /computer:hostname
```

Comment: Works very good. Do you know if I can pass a username and password which should be used for the connection? Or is there any documentation? I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working on Windows7. Don't ask me why, but this works. Set your "Target:" value to:

%windir%\system32\eventvwr.exe

i.e.
%windir%\system32\eventvwr.exe johnnysLaptop.ad.com

The ".exe" extension seems to do something magical to the Event Viewer start-up process (aka MMC.exe).

Johnny

Answer (score -2):

This works on Windows 7.  In a batch file or on the commandline you can use this:

```
start eventvwr computername
```