# How to connect from command line to another computer with Event Viewer as another user?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, windows-event-log, eventviewer

I am trying to connect to another computer with Event Viewer from command line.  And it can be [done](https://serverfault.com/questions/174241/shortcut-for-eventvwr-connect-to-another-computer).

However, I need to connect as another user (not my logged in user).  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command worked for me:

**C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:domain\user "cmd /c \"eventvwr computername\""**

Don't forget to change 'domain\user' and 'computername'.